# fopen through snprintf

Tags: c, file, printf, fopen

I'm having issues compiling my program that otherwise works fine, however, whilst trying to condense `strcpy` & `strcat` into `snprintf` (to remove unnecessary lines of code), upon compiling the warning

> passing argument 2 of ‘snprintf’ makes integer from pointer without a cast

presents itself. I've tried searching around for others with this problem, however once adapted their solutions appear to not work with my code

`fileDir` is defined at start of program as: `char fileDir[1000];`

`event->name` is the name of a file (and its extension), e.g. picture1.jpg.

`hashDirectory` is `"/home/user/Documents/_Hash"`.

```
FILE *ftest2=fopen(snprintf(fileDir, "%s: %s: %s", hashDirectory, event->name, ".txt"), "wt");
```

I can open the file however that is only when I use `strcpy` and `strcat` - which is what I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: One really, really bad side effect of stuffing way too much code into one line is not being able to debug it when it doesn't work....

Comment: That's because the second parameter is a `size_t` and not a string. Check the documentation of the function here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/ and fix your function call accordingly.

Comment: @Blaze ...and because `snprintf` returns `int`, while `fopen` accepts `const char *` as its first argument.

Comment: What filenames do you want to create? You have a filename including extension and add `": .txt"` to it

Comment: @Gerhardh just a .txt file but removing the original file extension is a problem for another time haha.

Comment: @Blaze & StaceyGirl much appreciated, thank you

Comment: OK. But what file names do you want to create? Is `"/home/user/Documents/_Hash: picture1.jpg: .txt`" what you want?

Comment: @Gerhardh oh sorry. The file name I would like is (for example in the case of picture1.jpg) picture1.txt (I wish all to have the .txt extension). The file names will change due to event-name changing, therefore not all will be called the same thing of course.

Comment: Then the colons and spaces and the prefix path are not intented? You should use `snprintf` in a separate line first and check what filename you actually create before you try to open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few problems with your code as evidenced by all of the comments.

For now we'll skip the [`fopen`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html) and focus on the [`snprintf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html). `snprintf` is just like `printf` except there are two additional arguments that you need to pass first, a `char *` indicating where to store the rendered character data, and a `size_t` that indicates how much space is available at the `char *`. The idiomatic way to do this (assuming a `char[]` is the destination) is to use `sizeof()` like this:

```
int res = snprintf(fileDir, sizeof(fileDir), /* Other arguments omitted */);
```

`snprintf` returns the number of characters that were printed (as an `int`). If that number is greater than or equal to `sizeof(fileDir)` then whatever is in `fileDir` will be truncated (but will always be `NULL` terminated).

```
if (res >= sizeof(fileDir)) {
    /* fileDir contains an incomplete path, handle this as an error */
}
```

Finally, because the return value of `snprintf` is an `int`, you can't pass that as the first argument to `fopen` because that expects the first argument to be a `const char *`. So these need to be separate steps.

Having said all of this, the way that you are building the path appears to be incorrect as well. In the full example below, I have fixed it:

```
FILE *ftest2;

int res = snprintf(fileDir, sizeof(fileDir), "%s/%s.txt", hashDirectory, event->name);
if (res >= sizeof(fileDir)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "The pathname was truncated. Cannot proceed.\n");
    return -1;
}

ftest2 = fopen(fileDir, "wt");
if (!ftest2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open `%s': %s\n", fileDir, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

/* Rest of your code */
```

An important note, if the first argument to `snprintf` was a a pointer to dynamically allocated memory (i.e. from `malloc`), you wouldn't be able to use `sizeof()` and instead would need to pass the size of the dynamically allocated region explicitly. `sizeof()` is evaulated at compile time (ignoring [VLAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)), not at runtime.

*(You'll need to `#include` `string.h` and `errno.h` for the `strerror()` call to work if you want to use that part)*